# Get source xml of error

Tags: magento2, error, xml, debugging

Is there a way to resolve any xml-file that causes an error?

I cannot find the source file that causes this error (happens on checkout):

```
Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'item', attribute 'after': The attribute 'after' is not allowed.
Line: 1439
```

default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>

    <!-- Removing / Moving -->
    <referenceBlock name="advanced-search-link" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="header" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />

    <move element="minicart" destination="header-wrapper" after="-" />
    <move element="form.subscribe" destination="footer" after="footer.copyright" />


    <!--minicart popup-->


    <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
        <container name="header.socialmedia.container" before="logo">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/socialmedia.phtml" name="header.socialmedia" />
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="header.retailer-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Become Retailer</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">retailer</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/accountmenu.phtml" name="header.accountmenu" />
    </referenceBlock>


     <!-- Footer -->
    <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="copyright" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true" />

    <referenceContainer name="footer">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/footer/logo.phtml" name="footer.logo" />
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/footer/menublocks.phtml" name="footer.menublocks" />
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/footer/copyright.phtml" name="footer.copyright" />
    </referenceContainer>


    <!-- Removing stuff -->
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
        <!-- <referenceBlock name="catalogsearch.leftnav" remove="true"/> -->
        <!-- <referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true"/> -->
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="sale.reorder.sidebar" remove="true" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>

    <move element="cart.summary" destination="main.content" after="-" />
    <move element="checkout.cart.coupon" destination="main.content" before="checkout.cart.crosssell"/>
    <move element="checkout.cart.crosssell" destination="main.content" after="-" />

    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper" htmlClass="page-wrapper cart">
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceContainer name="content">



    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.shipping">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="block-summary" xsi:type="array">

                        <!-- My custom part: -->
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>

                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

checkout_index_index.xml contains no xml changes

Comment: please share your default.xml code from theme level Magento_Theme.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya see updated answer. My error happens on checkout page btw

Comment: please share your xml file from checkout module/theme which contains after atttribute

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya updated answer

Comment: @Bram error looks like you have added after attributes in referenceContainer somewhere. Please check it may issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is no. :( If you trying to debug the `Magento\Framework\Config\Dom` class you can see that all data has stored in the memory as a one big file, which leads to unknown place (in my case there was a root directory `/var/www/html`):

[image: example]

So here are some tips:

1. Try to determine the error location by indirect signs: what modules was setted up before the error comes, which file has *%1* node and *%2* attribute etc.
2. Try to search in your project files by keywords *%1* and *%2* in the xml files.

*%1* - 'item'
*%2* - 'after'

3. If you are using the **PhpStorm** IDE (or similar) you can add the magento `.xsd` schemas in the settings to enable auto-validation during development:

[image: schemas]

As a result you able to see highlighted errors if some of a `.xml` files has invalid attributes:

[image: result]

4. Good similar tool which does that automatically (for the **PhpStorm**) is [PhpStorm Magento 2 Plugin](https://github.com/magento/magento2-phpstorm-plugin)

---

#### How to add the `.xsd` mapping manually in the PhpStorm

Go to the *Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Schemas and DTDs* click on the `+` sign, in the URI field add the `xsd` path (from the corresponding `xml` file, could be found as an attribute `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` of the root config node in almost each magento `xml` file:

[image: where schema could be found in xml]

then find corresponding schema location from a project schema list:

[image: project schema list]

Click `OK`.

---

#### How to use *PhpStorm* code inspector to validate project xml-files

It's pretty simple:

- Right-click on the project root directory [image: inspect code menu]
- Select *Inspect Code...*
- Click on the `...` button near *Inspection Profile* select [image: menu button in the inspection profile]
- In opened window click on the *Gear* symbol on the right of the profile name and select *Duplicate* [image: inspection profile settings]
- Type a name, something like *XML inspection*, uncheck all checkboxes except the `XML` one (you can use the *eraser* button on the top of list)
- Click `OK` to save the profile (window closing)
- Click `OK` to start check
- Analise the result :) [image: Example of code inspection by XML]

Comment: Ah thanks for the tips! I use phpstorm (editing files remotely, so I need to have it locally first before I can do this). So the xsd validation will go over your whole project?

Comment: @Bram yes, it will validate each file where schema exists

Comment: Hi, @SiarheyUchukhlebau, Please explain how to apply this?

Comment: @kunj Hi, what exactly you wish to apply?

Comment: How did you add those `.xsd` in Phpstorm?

Comment: Yeah, I can't figure that out either

Comment: @kunj Go to the *Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Schemas and DTDs* click on the `+` sign, in the `URI` field add the `xsd` path (from the corresponding xml file, could be found as an attribute `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` of the root `config` node in almost each magento `xml` file: https://gyazo.com/73459ff698253436b21640a468ba14a6 ) then find corresponding schema location from a project schema list: https://gyazo.com/ff18aed3511c2d9459c8dba716efe3fa . Click `OK`.

Comment: @kunj Another way is to use plugin (see #4 in the answer) or to use the script described here by Alan Kent https://alankent.me/2015/10/07/xml-schema-resolution-in-php-storm-with-urns-quick-note/

Comment: Okay, the plugin added them automatically. Now how do I scan all my xml files for errors? That is the last thing I cant figure out

Comment: @Bram, which plugin are you using?

Comment: The magento2 plugin for phpstorm. Just go to preferences -> plugins -> search for Magento Phpstorm and add it. Then restart, go again to preferences, select 'Enable for this project', and regenerate urn map.

Comment: @Bram It's pretty simple: right-click on the project root directory > select *Inspect Code...* > Click on the `...` button near *Inspection Profile* select > In opened window click on the gear on the right of the profile name and select *Duplicate* > Type a name, something like *XML inspection*, uncheck all checkboxes except the `XML` one (you can use the eraser button on the top of list) > Click *OK* to save profile (window closing) > Click *OK* to start check > Analise the result https://gyazo.com/e5fbdcc3d4c492ddbfdf04f0819eaf8d :)

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau, thank you so much, +1 for you.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau thank you, very valuable information!