# Layout XML Error - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.2, layout, blocks

I change the deploy mode to developer on Magento 2 and now I see the following error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( title, css, link, meta, script, remove, attribute ).
Line: 642


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( title, css, link, meta, script, remove, attribute ).
Line: 642

#0 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<layout xmlns:x...')
#1 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:x...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, NULL, '/home/fitvehic/...', '%message%\nLine:...')
#2 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#3 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#4 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php(42): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#5 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php(141): Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(Array)
#6 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(461): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('<layout xmlns:x...', 'layout_merged', false)
#7 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(442): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_frontend...', '<body>\n   <refe...')
#8 /public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load(Array)
#9 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load()
#10 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(63): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates()
#11 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(254): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#12 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(875): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#13 /public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(414): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('page_content_he...')
#14 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('page_content_he...')
#15 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Index/Index.php(43): Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), 'grandesport_lay...')
#16 /public_html/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index->execute(NULL)
#17 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute()
#18 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#20 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /public_html/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#22 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#25 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#31 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#33 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#34 /public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#35 {main}
```

Also in the debug file I have this:

```
[2019-07-01 19:44:46] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_4dd32ce4e9a4da9f99b408194db562ca2 and handles default, customer_account_create: Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'block': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( title, css, link, meta, script, remove, attribute ).
Line: 642
 [] []
[2019-07-01 19:46:25] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_4999a55d7d9f00b9a016b5e16762ce70a and handles default, customer_account_login: Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'block': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( title, css, link, meta, script, remove, attribute ).
Line: 642
 [] []
[2019-07-01 19:46:30] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_41a25b71f07a44338e9e39cdd0ac4a8b7 and handles default, cms_index_index, cms_page_view, cms_index_index_id_grandesport_layout2_home: Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'block': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( title, css, link, meta, script, remove, attribute ).
Line: 642
```

what I can do to find where is the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errors are invalid XML

There is a plugin for PHPstorm editor

https://github.com/magento/magento2-phpstorm-plugin

You can then generate XML URN map to validate against.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/101524/70343

Or better yet you can scan your code. I was going to type an answer on how to use it but then I came across this

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/227343/70343

The part you are interested in is 'How to use *PhpStorm* code inspector to validate project xml-files'

Let me know if any detail gets lost in translation.

But basically after generating the URN you can scan your code.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it.