# Magento 2.2.9 product page won't load

Tags: magento2.2

I am having an issue that I don't fully understand why the product page won't load. I am on Magento 2.2.9 using VES Floristry theme from Land of Coder. I have a ticket in with them, but frankly, I'm a little underwhelmed with their service of late and would like to get this fixed if it's indeed something simple. Below is the error when I try to access a product page like http://m2.vulcansrest.com/shibori-knitted-felt.html

I have a hunch the theme has some old cold from M2.1.x and I don't think M2.2.x supports , but its a little advance for me right now.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'move', attribute 'name': The attribute 'name' is not allowed.
Line: 1346

Element 'move', attribute 'name': The attribute 'name' is not allowed.
Line: 1347

Element 'move', attribute 'name': The attribute 'name' is not allowed.
Line: 1348


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'move', attribute 'name': The attribute 'name' is not allowed.
Line: 1346

Element 'move', attribute 'name': The attribute 'name' is not allowed.
Line: 1347

Element 'move', attribute 'name': The attribute 'name' is not allowed.
Line: 1348

<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php:42]
#5 Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php:141]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php:479]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php:455]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge/Interceptor.php:193]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:86]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:63]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:253]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:875]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:414]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock() called at [vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php:171]
#15 Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage() called at [vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Noroute/Index.php:44]
#16 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index->execute() called at [generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Noroute/Index/Interceptor.php:24]
#17 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:107]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#19 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#20 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#21 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Noroute/Index/Interceptor.php:39]
#22 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:55]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#24 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#25 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:94]
#26 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#27 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:73]
#28 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#29 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#30 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#31 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:136]
#32 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#33 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:257]
#34 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are running developer mode

If you turn this off you should not see these errors

However to debug this have a look at this

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/280354/70343

But in summary caused by invalid XML within the theme