# Finding Source of Exception: Attribute is Not Allowed

Tags: magento2, exception

After updating to a new version of Magento, our store is giving us the following exception:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'meta', attribute 'property': The attribute 'property' is not allowed.
Line: 993


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'meta', attribute 'property': The attribute 'property' is not allowed.
Line: 993

<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php:42]
#5 Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php:141]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php:479]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php:455]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge/Interceptor.php:193]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:86]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:63]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:253]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:875]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:414]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock() called at [vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php:171]
#15 Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage() called at [vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Index/Index.php:68]
#16 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index->execute() called at [generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php:24]
#17 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:107]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#19 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#20 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [app/code/Anowave/Ec/Plugin/App/Action/Context.php:148]
#21 Anowave\Ec\Plugin\App\Action\Context->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#22 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#23 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php:39]
#24 Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:55]
#25 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#27 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:94]
#28 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#29 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:69]
#30 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#31 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#32 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#33 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:136]
#34 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#35 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:257]
#36 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:37]
</pre>
```

I understand that I should be looking for a meta tag with a property attribute, but I've been unable to locate it in the codebase. Is there a way for me to hone in on the source of this exception?

Comment: Error need to be in the head element and should go like this 

`<meta name="description" content=XXX"/>`

Comment: It was the property attribute, so `<meta property="blah"/>`

Comment: I knew I was looking for that tag, I was hoping for clues on where to find which file it was in. The other answers are more helpful in that regard.

Comment: glad you found solution.

Comment: Thank you, @MohitRane !

Answer (score 1):

Check this thread, it may help: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11116

Comment: This particular comment helped a lot: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11116#issuecomment-351354102
(Editing /vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php so that the document throwing the exception is logged)

Answer (score 1):

This error would suggest invalid XML in your theme and / or extensions. There is a plugin for PHPstorm editor

https://github.com/magento/magento2-phpstorm-plugin

You can then generate XML URN map to validate against.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/101524/70343

Or better yet you can scan your code. I was going to type an answer on how to use it but then I came across this

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/227343/70343

The part you are interested in is 'How to use PhpStorm code inspector to validate project xml-files'

Let me know if any detail gets lost in translation.

But basically after generating the URN you can scan your XML code.

[image: Sceenshot of me scanning XML code]